# python 2.7 : How to read a simple number from a text file, execute a simple add operation on it an write the result back

Tags: python

a really simple question from a beginner.

I'm trying to read a simple number from a text file, do some mathematic with it and write the answer back.

I know it sounds easy, but i'm a real beginner.

thanks in advance

Michel

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with?  Break it down into parts.  First open the file.  then read a line from the file.  then convert that line into a number, etc. etc.  If you run into a *specific* problem, that's a lot easier for us to help you with in a meaningful way.

Comment: try googling around and learn how to do it. It is fun learning new things

Comment: no code, no research on your own.. sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    num = int(f.readline())

# perform calculations

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    print >>f, num
```

Comment: Really?  You're gonna pull out the `print >>` syntax on this poor user?  :-P

Comment: @mgilson: The OP wouldn't have put "Python 2.7" right there in the title of his question unless he wanted to make absolutely sure the answer didn't work in 3.x, and what better way to ensure that? The problem is that this code will still work in 1.2-2.6. To fix that, maybe `print >>f, ({1, 2}, num)[1]`?

Comment: Thanks Jamulak, I will try that tonight :-)

Comment: @mgilson I'm not settling for `f.write(str(num))`, do you suggest `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: @jamylak But you didn't show him how to perform all his calculations, he'll never be able to properly get it done without them.

Comment: @abarnert -- That comment has me sitting here laughing and now my co-workers are even more certain of the fact that I'm slightly insane.  Thanks for that :)

Comment: @abarnert does that code still work in `0.0` - `1.1` ?

Comment: @jamylak: Well, 0.9 was the first version, not 0.0. But I can't find docs or what's new or code going back before 1.2, and I didn't want to guess. But I'm willing to bet that, whether 0.9 had `print >>` or not, `{1, 2}` is not legal, so that will fix the problem if it exists.